# Can you tell who installed a program in Windows Vista or Windows 7 Home Premium?

Tags: windows

Every few months relatives call me to "diagnose" their home computers and I often notice that there's new applications installed in `C:\Program Files`.  I could tell by its folder's or its data file's Creation Date when it happened, but where can I find out which user account did it or which Administrator account allowed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scanning though Windows's Event Log should give it away.